# Liferay Portal Instances // Change URL Binding

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I was wondering if I can change the URL binding of a Liferay portal instance some time after creation.

I am planning to develop a new website based on Liferay (as of now it looks like we're using 6.1 oder newer) and launch it under an existing domain (after completion). Since I don't want to affect the site currently running under this domain, I was thinking I could use a sub domain during development.

So here is my scenario:

- This new site is the first of several websites which will be come
  later. Those sites will all be running in the same Liferay.
- Since I don't wanna mix several sites, I was thinking of using portal
  instances.
- So I wanna use dev.domain.com during development without affecting
  www.domain.com. So far, so good.

**My question is:** Can I change the portal instance after from dev.domain.com to www.domain.com without having to create a new one? So all I'd need to do to go live is change the subdomain and change some Apache vhost-settings.

Portal instances need a web Id, virtual host, mail domain and max users count. 
After creation, I cannot change the web id.

- What is the main setting here?
- Which one is used to map my portal instance to the URL?
- Could it be enough to change the virtual host from dev.domain.com to
  www.domain.com?

Thanks for your help and regards
Sebastian

Comment: Check out the "virtual host" and "friendly URL" settings for your site (somewhere in "Manage Pages")

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to have dev and testing done before going live LR provides a great mechanism for that using the Staging Server option. This has been further enhanced in LR ver 6.2.

You can do your dev & testing on the staging server (switch on staging option) and seamlessly update from staging to production. The new version also validates and warns of potential inconsistencies.

You can also setup remote staging (normally staging could be in the same server) and disable live updates to production. You can also use a preshared key in 6.2 for secure updates from staging to production

Check documentation for further details.